# Singleton class not getting mocked

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, powermock, easymock

I have a singleton class SvnPlugin whose getInstance() i need to mock to return a mock object. But it's not getting mocked. I am using Powermock and Easymock.

Following is my test code

```
@Test
@PrepareForTest({SVNPlugin.class})
public void createGlobalUSerTest() throws Exception{
    PowerMock.mockStatic(SVNPlugin.class);
    SVNPlugin svnPlugin=PowerMock.createMock(SVNPlugin.class);
    PowerMock.expectNew(SVNPlugin.class).andReturn(svnPlugin);      

    EasyMock.expect(SVNPlugin.getInstance()).andReturn(svnPlugin).anyTimes();
    EasyMock.expect(svnPlugin.getSynProject("", "", "", "")).andReturn(true);
    PowerMock.replay(SVNPlugin.class,svnPlugin);
    Future<RpcResult<CreateGlobalUserOutput>> 
       result=impl.createGlobalUser(getGLobalUser());
    PowerMock.verify(svnPlugin,SVNPlugin.class);
    Assert.assertNotNull(result);       
}
```

The sample code which it needs to mock is

```
SVNPlugin svnplugin = SVNPlugin.getInstance();
checkOutFlg = svnplugin.getSynProject(checkOutLocationAtLocal, svnPath , userName, passWord);
```

I am unable to understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is that you need the Powermock runner.

Then, in fact you don't need to mock `new` since mocking `getInstance` is enough.

I assumed that `SVNPlugin` is final, which justify the mock created with Powermock. So I tried with this implementation.

```
public final class SVNPlugin {
  public static SVNPlugin getInstance() {
    return new SVNPlugin();
  }

  private SVNPlugin() {}

  public boolean getSynProject(String s, String s1, String s2, String s3) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

And the following test is working perfectly.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class SVNPluginTest {

  @Test
  @PrepareForTest(SVNPlugin.class)
  public void createGlobalUSerTest() throws Exception{
    PowerMock.mockStatic(SVNPlugin.class);
    SVNPlugin svnPlugin = PowerMock.createMock(SVNPlugin.class);

    EasyMock.expect(SVNPlugin.getInstance()).andStubReturn(svnPlugin);
    EasyMock.expect(svnPlugin.getSynProject("", "", "", "")).andReturn(true);

    PowerMock.replay(SVNPlugin.class,svnPlugin);

    SVNPlugin svnplugin = SVNPlugin.getInstance();
    boolean checkOutFlg = svnplugin.getSynProject("", "", "", "");
    assertTrue(checkOutFlg);

    PowerMock.verify(svnPlugin,SVNPlugin.class);
  }
}
```